# Is this any kind of macro in linux kernel code?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

i found this in linux kernel code http://gitorious.org/pandroid/kernel-omap/blobs/5ed7607d45b300a37dd13ad1c79adea56f6687ce/arch/arm/mach-omap2/board-omap4panda.c

```
MACHINE_START(OMAP4_PANDA, "OMAP4430 Panda Board")
    .phys_io    = 0x48000000,
    .io_pg_offst    = ((0xfa000000) >> 18) & 0xfffc,
    .boot_params    = 0x80000100,
    .map_io     = omap_panda_map_io,
    .init_irq   = omap_panda_init_irq,
    .init_machine   = omap_panda_init,
    .timer      = &omap_timer,
MACHINE_END
```

i am not getting what is this..? is this a macro or structure or what..???

definition says

```
/*
 * Set of macros to define architecture features.  This is built into
 * a table by the linker.
 */
#define MACHINE_START(_type,_name)          \
static const struct machine_desc __mach_desc_##_type    \
 __used                         \
 __attribute__((__section__(".arch.info.init"))) = {    \
    .nr     = MACH_TYPE_##_type,        \
    .name       = _name,

#define MACHINE_END             \
};

#endif
```

but i am not understanding how's it work?

Comment: How long does it take to search for "#define MACHINE_START"?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever "About 19,100 results (**0.30 seconds**)" ;-))

Comment: You should learn how to get the preprocessed form of a source code. Replace `gcc` with `gcc -C -E` in the compilation command, and you'll get the preprocessed form on *stdout*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [designated structure initialization](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) is a GNU GCC extension which looks a bit strange if you are used to ANSI C compilers.  That combined with an ambitious macro makes it look like a foreign language in many respects.  The expanded source code is:

```
static const struct machine_desc __mach_desc_OMAP4_PANDA
 __used  __attribute__((__section__(".arch.info.init"))) = {
    .nr     = MACH_TYPE_OMAP4_PANDA,
    .name         = "OMAP4430 Panda Board",
    .phys_io      = 0x48000000,
    .io_pg_offst  = ((0xfa000000) >> 18) & 0xfffc,
    .boot_params  = 0x80000100,
    .map_io       = omap_panda_map_io,
    .init_irq     = omap_panda_init_irq,
    .init_machine = omap_panda_init,
    .timer        = &omap_timer,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

**MACHINE_START**

Defined as a preprocessor macro in:
[arch/arm/include/asm/mach/arch.h, line 67](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/mach/arch.h#L67)

**MACHINE_END**

Defined as a preprocessor macro in:
[arch/arm/include/asm/mach/arch.h, line 74](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/mach/arch.h#L74)

I use this site for Linux Kernel references
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's a designation initializer that initializes a structure object.